# Magento example.com/home being registered by Google as the home page

Tags: redirects

My website `example.com/home` is being registered by Google, that is not the home page because `example.com/` is the home page. Anyone can help me out on this? :(

Answer (score 1):

Set up a 301 Redirect for /home to go to /

If you wanted to you could also remove it from the index through Google Webmaster Tools however this can take some time to take effect.

Comment: Not sure why google see it as home page. How do i setup, i did read about it but they say redirect the page itself to /. i'm not sure where that file is located at , can i do a 301 redirect for [LINK] To [LINK]?

Comment: The reason that the /home URL exists is that in your CMS section in Magento the homepage I would suspect is under /home. This is the default setup for Magento.

To do the redirect you put the redirect in your .htaccess file at the root of your website files. There is an awful lot of examples for this around but at its simplest it can be:

Redirect 301 /home http://www.mysitename.com/

Comment: You can easily [handle this](http://www.designhaven.co.uk/2012/12/permanently-301-redirecting-home-in-magento/) from the Magento back office  too if you aren't comfortable with mod_rewrite in .htaccess.